# JEE6 JAX-RS convert between APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED and APPLICATION_JSON

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs, java-ee-6

For reasons beyond my control I need a JAX-RS method that must consume and produce `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`

The body of the form posted will be like: `myJsonString={"id":"request123","someList":[{"itemId":"item234"}]}`

Ideally I'd like to implement my JAX-RS method like so:

```
@POST
@Path("/hello")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response hello(MyJsonObject myJsonObj) {
     return anotherJsonObj;
}
```

Can a Filter and/or Interceptor be used to convert the MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED to/from MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.

The JAX-RS method would then look like the above code and not need to know about MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED.

Any examples of how to do this appreciated.

Comment: I believe the standard way to do this (haven't actually done it myself) is with a custom `javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader`, as described in the JAX-RS spec in chapter "Providers". Registering one seems as simple as annotating with `@Provider`. Since the content of the posted data looks like JSON, it may be possible to extract the pure JSON part and delegate the parsing to the standard JAXB provider, i.e. reusing the existing implementation.